# Eigenvector and eigenvalue of differential operator $-\dfrac{d^2}{dx^2}+x^2$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, recurrence-relations, eigenfunctions

Let $Df=x^2f-f''$ and $Af=xf-f'$ on $L^2(\Bbb R)$, and define $e_0(x)=\pi^{-1/4}e^{-x^2/2}$ and $e_n=\dfrac1{\sqrt{2n}}A(e_{n-1})$. I would like to show that $e_n$ are eigenvectors (eigenfunctions) of $D$. If I compute $De_0(x)$ and $De_1(x)$ by definition above, I get

$D(e_0)(x)=\pi^{-1/4}e^{-x^2/2}=e_0(x)$, and since

$e_1(x)=\dfrac1{\sqrt{2}}x\pi^{-1/4}e^{-x^2/2}+\dfrac1{\sqrt{2}}x\pi^{-1/4}e^{-x^2/2}=\sqrt2x\pi^{-1/4}e^{-x^2/2}$, we have

$De_1(x)=x^2e_1(x)-e_1''(x)=x^3\sqrt2\pi^{-1/4}e^{-x^2/2}-\sqrt2\pi^{-1/4}e^{-x^2/2}(x^3-2x)=2e_1(x)$

But the commutator $[D,A]=(-\dfrac{d^2}{dx^2}+x^2)(x-\dfrac{d}{dx})-(x-\dfrac{d}{dx})(-\dfrac{d^2}{dx^2}+x^2)=2A$. Hence, $D(e_n)=D(\dfrac1{\sqrt{2n}}A(e_{n-1}))=\dfrac1{\sqrt{2n}}(AD+2A)(e_{n-1})=\dfrac1{\sqrt{2n}}(\lambda+2) A(e_{n-1})=(\lambda+2)e_{n-1}$, where $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue corresponding to $e_{n-1}$, provided $e_{n-1}$ is an eigenfunction of course. But then for $n=1$, that is, $\lambda=1$, I get $D(e_1)=3e_1\ne 2e_1$.

Where have I made a mistake?

Comment: You never introduced $H$, what is it?

Comment: Sorry, typo. H=D. I've edited the question now.

Comment: You have made a mistake in computing $De_1$. Please compute it again.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh it's suppose to be $De_1(x)=3e_1(x)$, correct? Thanks! (Also, I won't edit the question so you could post an answer below- if I edited it would kind of make the answer redundant in some way and thus people might not be inclined to answer, imho)

Comment: @Divide1918: The question does not require a separate answer. It is merely a calculation error. I think you have understood the problem and can solve it by yourself. Me (or anyone else for that matter) answering the question would not contribute to MSE in anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider two operators
$$A=-D+x, \quad B=D+x.$$
One has
$$AB=(-D+x)(D+x)=-D^{2}+x^{2}-1.$$
Moreover
$$AB-BA=[A,B]=-2.$$
So your original operator is
$$L=AB+1.$$
Consider a vector
$$e_{n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}}Ae_{n-1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^{n}n!}}A^{n}e_{0}.$$
We have
$$Le_{n}=ABe_{n}+e_{n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^{n}n!}}ABA^{n}e_{0}+e_{n}.$$
Note that
$$ABA^{n}=A^{2}BA^{n-1}+2A^{n}=A^{3}BA^{n-2}+4A^{n}$$
$$=A^{4}BA^{n-3}+6A^{n}=...=A^{n}AB+2nA^{n}.$$
Further we noted $Be_{0}=0$ and thus
$$Le_{n}=\frac{2n}{\sqrt{2^{n}n!}}A^{n}e_{0}+e_{n}=(2n+1)e_{n}.$$

This solves your problem!